# How to display sub menu in right for a left side menu with custom scroll and fixed position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have done already the custom scroll for my left side menu, but the issue comes when I am trying to display the sub menu to right side of my "leftsidemenu" its hidden inside the scroll div

I have added the submenu in  left menu 3 for testing purpose

**trying to achieve in this pattern**
[image]

**below is the code**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
/*scroll*/
  var $scrollable = $('.scrollable');
  var $scrollbar  = $('.scrollbar');
   var $windowHeight = $(window);
  $scrollable.outerHeight(true);
  var H   = $windowHeight.outerHeight(true);
  var sH  = $scrollable[0].scrollHeight;
  var  sbH = H*H/sH;



$('.scrollbar').height(sbH);

$scrollable.on("scroll", function(){

    $scrollbar.css({top: $scrollable.scrollTop()/H*sbH });
});
/*menu*/
 var parentHeight = $(window).height();
 $(".parent").css({"height":parentHeight})
 $(window).resize(function(){
 var parentHeight = $(window).height();
 $(".parent").css({"height":parentHeight})
 });
 $("#leftSideMenu li[class='dropdown']").on("click", function(){
     $(".dropdown-list",this).toggle();
 })
});
```

```css
/*scroll css*/
.parent{
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:230px;
    background:#ddd;
 float:left;
}
.scrollable{
      overflow-y:scroll;
   overflow-x:hidden;
      width: 250px;
      height:100%;

}
.scrollbar{

    position:absolute;
    overflow:auto;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    z-index:2;
    background:#444;
    width:7px;
    border-radius:5px;
 opacity:0.7;
}

/*menu*/
#leftSideMenu { width:250px; }
#leftSideMenu ul { list-style:none; padding:0; margin:0; background-color:#0FACF3; }
#leftSideMenu ul li {  }
#leftSideMenu ul li a { padding:15px 5px; display:block; color:#fff; font-size:14px; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;}
#leftSideMenu ul li .dropdown-list { display:none; left:250px; position:absolute; z-index:10000;}
#leftSideMenu ul li .dropdown-list li a { padding:10px 15px 10px 25px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="parent">
            <div class="scrollbar"></div>
            <div class="scrollable">
<div id="leftSideMenu">
<ul>
<li><a href="#" >Left Menu 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Left Menu 2</a>
</li>
<li class="dropdown"><a href="#" >Left Menu 3</a>
<ul class="dropdown-list">
<li><a href="#" >Sub Left Menu 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Sub Left Menu 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Sub Left Menu 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Sub Left Menu 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Sub Left Menu 5</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Sub Left Menu 6</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#" >Left Menu 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Left Menu 5</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Left Menu 6</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Left Menu 7</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Left Menu 8</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Left Menu 9</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Left Menu 10</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Left Menu 11</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Left Menu 12</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Left Menu 13</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Left Menu 14</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Left Menu 15</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Left Menu 8</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Left Menu 9</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Left Menu 10</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Left Menu 11</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Left Menu 12</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Left Menu 13</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Left Menu 14</a></li>
<li><a href="#" >Left Menu 15</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="float:left;">test data</div>
```

**jsfiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/1w69s2tt/

Comment: It's probably hidden because of `overflow: hidden` and  `overflow-x: hidden` - try changing/removing these

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/

Comment: @VXp I tried your solution but its not working due to the fixed position for the menu

Comment: Do it without the fixed position, you can make it happen, customize the given example to your needs.